# Custom event not firing in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, custom-component, custom-event

I have 2 custom components in Flash Builder, A.mxml which contains B.mxml. B has a text input, and every time the text is changed I would like to call a "save()" function on A.

The relevant code in B is:

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="customChange", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

...

<s:TextInput text="@{value}" valueCommit="{dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE))}"/>
```

I can replace the code in `valueCommit="{}"` with a trace statement, and confirm that it's working as expected.

The relevant code in A is:

```
<widgets:B customChange="{save()}"/>
```

However `save()` is never getting called.

Why is the event not reaching A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata in your class (B.mxml) says it dispatches an event who's type/name is "customChange":

```
[Event(name="customChange", type="flash.events.Event")]
```

But the component is dispatching `Event.CHANGE` -- the type/name for this event is just "change".

You have two options:

- Change your meta data to use the the same event type/name that you are dispatching:

  [Event(name="change", type="flash.events.Event")]
- Create your own event class and dispatch that, then modify the meta data to specify that your custom event class is dispatched by B.mxml

Comment: Aha, I thought the name field simply indicated what you wanted the property on the MXML widget to be called. Thanks for the clarification!